# CPU fan failing to start on boot sometimes

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have a fairly old desktop, which I like to use a fair bit over my newer PC's however sometimes on boot, the CPU fan fails to start. I had this problem previously, and I simply bought a new fan. I have the alarm set in the BIOS menu to warn me if the Fan fails or isn't operating as normal.

I was wondering if it could be the power supply possibly? My current power supply is 300W, which I know is quite low.

Also another thing to note is that it doesn't happen every single boot, however it is getting more and more frequent. To fix it, I generally turn the power switch off at the back and then turn it back on and reboot the computer. And every time I boot my computer I get the alarm for like a second, but I do believe this is normal as it hasn't had the chance to be powered yet.

Is there a fix to this issue?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, have you cleaned the fan?

Comment: Yes I have :) I recently only just purchased the fan 2 months ago, so there wasn't much dust there when I cleaned it to begin with.

Comment: You're only options with something like this are to replace the components. You've already done the fan, so that leaves the power supply and the power switch.

Comment: Yer I guess so. I will purchase a new power supply and update this if it still persists. It stopped occurring after I purchased the new fan for like a few weeks, and everything worked smoothly, then it just gradually started getting worse and worse.